# Why does David go back instead of just telling Christina that he has feelings for her?

Tags: plot-explanation, project-almanac

In Project Almanac, the group made a pact/promise that they would only go back together as a group, never individually.

At the music festival, when David doesn't kiss Christina, he goes back on his own because he knows that she wanted him to at that moment and they could be together.

I get that he may be embarrassed about the whole thing, but why doesn't he just put it aside and get everyone together and explain that they need to go back? He could even tell Christina that he missed the moment at the festival but he can fix it.

Also, why does he actually go back to that moment at the festival to kiss her, why doesn't he just kiss her in the basement and tell her how he feels, surely they'd get together then anyway?

Answer (score 1):

David's decisions in the movie are what cause all of the problems in the first place. Every time he thinks he's messed something up, he decides to break the pact of "time traveling together" and goes on his own to "fix" his mistakes. In the process he creates more mistakes and it keeps compounding until the point where he needs to go back all the way to that birthday party of his to undo everything.

He doesn't stop there. The David from the new timeline finds two cameras and now he wants to time travel more and keep messing things up endlessly.

That is David's character. If he had the maturity to later kiss her in the basement and tell her how he feels, he wouldn't have broken the pact either. He doesn't do it because he prefers to simply rewrite the past as he considers it to be less hassle (but it's not).